# getting rows from db and add them to list of type object

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

I have databases which have some rows, i want to fetch all of the data in the table and add them to list of object type ..

I tried this:

```
var dbClient = await database;
result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $newsTable');
for (var n in result){
  favNews.add(n);
}
```

where the list is:

```
List<NewsModel> favNews = <NewsModel>[];
```

But am getting this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'NewsModel'
```

How can i get the result in the array of type news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

`rawQuery` returns `List<Map>` and when iterating of this list, your local variable in the loop `n` has the type `Map` which cannot be assigned to `NewsModel`.

You need to add some conversion methods to your model class `NewsModel` to convert from a `Map`.

There is even an [example in the sqflite documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#sql-helpers)!

```dart
class NewsModel {

  int id;
  String title;
  // ... more property

  NewsModel();

  NewsModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map["id"]
    title = map["title"]
    // ...
  }


}
```

and the in your database query code:

```dart
var dbClient = await database;
result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $newsTable');
for (var n in result){
  favNews.add(NewsModel.fromMap(v));
}
```